# Syntax for a parameter query in Python (pyodbc)

Tags: python, sql-server, parameters, pyodbc

I am trying to write results of some processing into SQL Server table.
My results are store in a list of lists where each item of the list is a list. I am using parameters (6 params) and I am getting the following error:

cnxn.execute(sqlStatement, (item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4],item[5]))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 6 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

That's my code

```
sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO CEA_CR (`SessionID`, `Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned`, `Session.Did_Call_Type_happen_on_this_call`, `Session.Was_there_a_system_or_Rep_generated_Memo_that_matches_with_Call_Type` , 'cycle' , 'version')  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s ,%s ,%s)"

for item in result:
     wr.writerow(item)
     cnxn.execute(sqlStatement, (item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4],item[5]))
     cnxn.commit()
```

Anyone knows why my execution fails ?

Comment: I don't know what sql driver you are using, but shouldn't the parameter replacements be `?` instead of `%s`? https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 3):

You should be using ? as parameter markers I believe.

Your sql should probably look like this:

```
sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO CEA_CR (SessionID, Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned, Session.Did_Call_Type_happen_on_this_call, Session.Was_there_a_system_or_Rep_generated_Memo_that_matches_with_Call_Type, cycle, version) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Comment: I corrected my statement to :      sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO CEA_CR (`SessionID`, `Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned`, `Session.Did_Call_Type_happen_on_this_call`, `Session.Was_there_a_system_or_Rep_generated_Memo_that_matches_with_Call_Type` , 'cycle' , 'version')  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,?)"
but now the error message is : "Incorrect syntax near '`'"

Comment: It looks to me like Nonnib answered your original question.  Maybe you should accept this answer and ask a new one?  Also it's easier to give a completely correct answer if you post the complete, but minimal, code example.

Comment: The approach that's generally used in this type of situation is to try and simplify everything until you've worked out what the problem is.  Remove stuff till it works.  At that point you'll have more information of exactly where your problem is.

Comment: Why do cycle and version still have single quotes around them in your amended SQL above?